# Menus on the same line as the logo (html/css)

Tags: html, css, navigation, header

I'm setting up a site, and I want to put the menus on the same line as the logo (image), the problem is that the menus are put below anyway ... I think my css code has several contradictions that prevent menus from going to the right place. In short, I would like to create a **header with the logo on the left and the menus centered**!

There is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang=fr_FR>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <title>STADE BRESTOIS 29 - LE SITE OFFICIEL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navigation">
            <a href="#" class="logo" ><img src="logo_header.png" id="logo_header"></a>
            <div class="header">   
                <header id="header-center">
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li id="element">
                            <a href="#">Pro</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="element">
                            <a href="#">Formation</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="element">
                            <a href="#">Club</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="element">
                            <a href="#">Association</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="element">
                            <a href="#">Féminines</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </header>
            </div>
        </div>
    

    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS code :

```
@charset "utf-8";

@font-face{
    font-family: 'nagoda';
    src: url('Nagoda.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Nagoda.otf') format('otf'),
         url('Nagoda.ttf') format('ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#logo_header{
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 54px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
}

#menu{
    font-family: 'nagoda';
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    align-items: center;
}

#header{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    padding-top: 695px;
}

.header a {
    float: left;
    color: #383838;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px; 
    line-height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 70px;
}

.header a:hover {
    background-color: #ed1c24;
    color: white;
}

.header a.active {
    background-color: #ed1c24;
    color: white;
}

li {
    line-height: normal;
}

.header-center {
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .header a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .header-center {
      float: none;
    }
}

body {
    background-image: url(Image_bg1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: local;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 1440px;
    height: 695px;
}
```

Thanks in advance to those who will try to help me!

Answer (score 0):

I changed z little your css

```
<style>
    @charset "utf-8";

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'nagoda';
      src: url('Nagoda.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Nagoda.otf') format('otf'),
        url('Nagoda.ttf') format('ttf');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    .navigation {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #logo_header {
      height: 110px;
      width: 110px;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-left: 54px;
      margin-top: 25px;
    }

    ul {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #menu {
      font-family: 'nagoda';
      font-size: 25px;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
      list-style-type: none;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #header {
      overflow: hidden;
      background: none;
      padding: 20px 10px;
      padding-top: 695px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    #menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .header a {
      color: #383838;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      line-height: 15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 70px;
    }

    .header a:hover {
      background-color: #ed1c24;
      color: white;
    }

    .header a.active {
      background-color: #ed1c24;
      color: white;
    }

    li {
      line-height: normal;
    }

    .header-center {
      height: 100px;
      width: 400px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }


    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .header a {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }

    body {
      background-image: url(Image_bg1.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
      background-attachment: local;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 1440px;
      height: 695px;
    }
  </style>
```

It is better to use flexbox than float. [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you have very good tutorial.

Comment: Thanks guy for your help, I looked at your flexbox guide and I understood how it works a lot better! I corrected my mistakes.

Comment: You welcome. You can use also for your body not a pixels but wv and hv like this: `width:100 wv;
 height: 100 hv;` or pourcentage % so your body takes all view of device ecran.